# conditionnally render prop in html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I am trying to set the closeModal prop when offline to true and else to closeModal. How do I achieve this ? I am using react-detect-offline and ant design.

```
        <Detector
                render={({ of }) => (
                    <ModalSelectMenu
                    {of ? closeModal = 'true' : closeModal = { closeModal }}
                        isModalVisible={isModalVisible}
                        history={history}   
                    />
                )}
            />
```

Comment: please try this ... `<ModalSelectMenu isModalVisible={isModalVisible} history={history} closeModal={offline ? 'true' : closeModal}/>` ... and share your feedback.

Comment: Your current code seems to imply you want the string `"true"`, is that accurate, or do you want the boolean `true`?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ModalMenu
  closeModal={offline ?'true' :  closeModal}
  isModalVisible={isModalVisible}
  history={history}   
 />
```